# How to show or save a resized image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize, scikit-image, opencv

I want to display and save the resized image. Below is the code for the same.

```
image = cv2.imread("zagreb_00050_11.png")

#plt.imshow(image)

image_sized=resize_keep_ar(image, 128)

plt.imshow(image_sized)

cv2.imwrite('resized_image.png',image_sized)
```

Resizing is done using the `skimage` module. First `plt.show()` works fine (commented), but after resizing when I tried to view the resized image it gives me below error.

```
ValueError: Unsupported dtype

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Also, when tried saving the resized image using `cv2.imwrite` I get the below error.

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try this `cv2.imwrite('resized_image.png',cv2.UMat(image_sized))` tip: you can use `cv2.resize(imgname,(size,size))` to resize image using opencv

Comment: This results in the below error.

`TypeError: UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)`

Thanks for the tip, but I am bound to use skimage due to requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it using `np.float32` instead of `cv2.UMat `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save try:

```
plt.imsave('resized_image.png', data)
```

or save the entire figure:

```
plt.savefig('resized_image.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
cv2.imwrite('resized_image.png', np.float32(image_sized))
```

instead of

```
cv2.imwrite('resized_image.png',image_sized)
```

solve the issue.